# "503: Server Unavailable. Your server appears to be down. Try restarting it from the hub". Help

Tags: qiskit, programming, ibm-q-experience

This message is popping continuously for 2 days in my IBM Quantum lab. I have tried logging out and in again, restarting the browser, changing the internet connection, and changing the device but this keeps showing.

[image]

Comment: Hello, would you be able to directly contact me on the Qiskit Slack via a DM? My user name there is Lena Perennes, I might help you unblock this but I'll need more information. The link is qiskit.slack.com :)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about quantum computing (just as a question about 503 error from DNAnexus cloud service would not be a question about genomics).

Answer (score 0):

503 Service Unavailable can be due to multiple reasons on IBM Quantum Lab based on my experience of running IBM Quantum Challenges when many users are accessing the platform at the same time. I can recommend the method `resetting your notebook pod` below which could solve the problem consistently during the challenges:

1. From the `File` menu in Quantum Lab, choose `Hub Control Panel`
2. Select `Stop My Lab` (this may take a minute), then select `Start My Server`.

[image]

[image]

See more in IBM Quantum Lab Documentation: https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/lab/docs/iql/troubleshooting#reset-your-notebook-pod